# C# Visualize assembly

Tags: c#

Is there any (free?) tools that let's me analyze an assembly?

This is (for now) what i want to visualize:

- All different types and their relations & coupling
- How my assembly is exposed to referencing assemblies. What types are internal or public.

I know of NDepend, but it feels heavy for my "simple" needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried Reflector from Red Gate? http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Gah, i use reflector daily and have not realized that internal types are greyed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The term "visualize" is hopelessly vague.  But your bullet list is well taken care of by Reflector.  It's free from RedGate.

Comment: Well, by visualize i mean that the application, in some way, can give me an easy overview of my different needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Redgate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) does show a lot.

In particular all available types, and it grays out internal types. You can use analyze a type to show who derives from it and a few other informations.

Answer (score 0):

Disclamer: I am part of the NDepend team.

Could you elaborate a bit on *NDepend feels heavy for my "simple" needs*. Sure NDepend has a large set of features, but you have the choice to just focus on its dependency oriented capabilities. As far as I know NDepend is the only tool that supports all kind of graphs:

- [Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Dep)
- [Call Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Call)
- [Class Inheritance Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Inherit)
- [Coupling Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Coupling)
- [Path Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Path)
- [All Paths Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#AllPaths)
- [Cycle Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Cycle)
- [Large Graph visualized with Dependency Structure Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Matrix)

[alt text http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.Graph/InternalDependenciesGraphSmall2.jpg](http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.Graph/InternalDependenciesGraphSmall2.jpg)

[image]